# How to return an error message from the Model?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, view, model, business-logic

In suppliment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129970/django-separation-of-business-logic-and-views-logic), if business logic should be in the model, how do I return an error message from the model?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if <some condition>:
        #return some error message to the view or template
```

Comment: Your business logic (whether in the model, model manager or else where) can simply raise an exception that can be caught at the view level and a meaningful error reported to the user (or some sort of error handling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pastylegs is correct, but you shouldn't be doing that sort of logic in the `save` method. Django has a built-in system for [validating model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) before saving - you should use this, and raise `ValidationError` where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Raising an exception is the way to report a program logic error (an error in 'business logic'), which is what you are talking about. You can just raise an Exception, as pastylegs proposes (be aware that SomeException is just a placeholder):

```
from django.core.exceptions import SomeException

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if <some condition>:
        raise SomeException('your message here')
```

You can find the available exceptions fpr django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/exceptions/ ,plus you can also use the standard python exceptions, for which you can find documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

I would recommend you to find an Exception that describes your problem, or you will be pretty confused if that error shows up in a few weeks, when you cannot remember what exactly you have been doing now.

Comment: This answer is fine from a python point of view, but not really appropriate for Django. Almost all Django views are written with the assumption that the instance is valid before the save method is called. Therefore the views won't catch the exception, and your your user will get a 500 server error message. See Daniel's answer for the correct approach in Django.