# How to show errors raised by the model?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, view, model, business-logic

In a django view, how do I show errors raised by the model?

This is a follow up question for this [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531850/how-to-return-an-error-message-from-the-model/9532107#9532107).

Answer (score 1):

Actually Django makes it easier than *stealing a piece of cake from a 1 year old baby*. **All you need is to write a [process_exception()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) function in a class that should be added to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**. Based on that, you can take error handling pretty far.

You can create a middleware.py file in your project root. Then add it to settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    # [....] all other middlewares above
    'middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',
]
```

If you have the great django-sentry, you probably only want to handle **some** exceptions, and leave the rest to django-sentry. In that case, you can create such a setting:

```
EXCEPTION_MIDDLEWARE_HANDLES = [
    'ServerOverloaded',
    # [...] other exception class names that you want to handle in your middleware
    'BetTooLateException',
]
```

I'm going to show you an **example middleware** that implements process_request() and handles exceptions which class names are in EXCEPTION_MIDDLEWARE_HANDLES. It might not exactly suit your need, but it's really `trivial to adapt to your own needs`:

```
from django import http
from django import template
from django.template import loader
from django.conf import settings

class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if settings.DEBUG: # don't do anything in debug mode
            return None

        # here i use a setting because i want some exception to be caught by sentry
        # but you can remove this if you want your middleware to handle all exceptions
        if exception.__class__.__name__ not in settings.EXCEPTION_MIDDLEWARE_HANDLES:
            return None

        # time to prepare the error response
        context = {
            'error': exception.__class__.__name__,
            'exception': exception,
        }  

        response = http.HttpResponse(
            loader.render_to_string(
                'error.html',
                context,
                context_instance=template.RequestContext(request)
            ), 
            status=504
        )  

        # maybe it'll be fixed in 5 minutes ? tell bots to come back
        response['Retry-After'] = 5*60
        return response
```

Verbosity takes place in **template/error.html**:

```
{% extends 'site_base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block body %} 
    <h1>{% trans 'Oopsie' %} !</h1>

    <p>
    {% if error == 'ServerOverloaded' %}
        {% blocktrans %}It's not your fault but our data provider is overloaded for the moment - and we don't have any cached version of the data you requested. Our techie has been notified but it's unlikely that he can do anything about it. Would you please try again later ?{% endblocktrans %}
    {% endif %}

    [.......]

    {% if error == 'BetTooLateException' %}
        {% with exception.bet.session as session %}
        {% blocktrans %}You may not bet on {{ session }} because it has already started.{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Try to detail the errors as much as possible and **especially** avoid to stress the user. Think of the senior neophytes whom will read your error message. In the case of the first exception, I think it's pretty clear that the user didn't do anything wrong and that it's temporary.

In the other case, BetTooLateException, well we probably just busted a cheater :)

And BTW, BetTooLateException is **thrown by the model - from a pre_save signal**. So that's probably quite similar to what you're trying to do according to what I understand from your previous questions.